# Getting error while loading android studio, Unable to load class 'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider'

Tags: java, android

I upgraded the Android Studio to latest version (3.0.1) . Now i am not able to open or create new project because of following error

```
Error:(1, 0) Unable to load 
class'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.I did the following steps.
1) Delete all files in 'C:\Users\.gradle' directory
2) Then run Android studio as Admin